# How to detect when a drop does not finish on a sensitive view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I'm implementing drag and drop functionality. I have a scenario where I need to detect when a drop does not finish on a sensitive view. I'm using the onDrop(of:isTargeted:perform:) modifier to handle drop events, but I couldn't find a direct callback for when the drop exits the sensitive view.

I've tried implementing a custom DropDelegate and using the dropExited(info:) method to handle the scenario, but it doesn't seem to get called in this case.

Is there a recommended approach or workaround to detect when a drop exits a sensitive view in SwiftUI? Ideally, I would like to perform specific actions when the drop exits the view.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have added a delegate:

```
struct ButtonDropDelegate: DropDelegate {

    
    func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
        sharedState.dragStarted = false
    }
}
```

But `dropExited` not get called at all.

This is where `drag` is trieggered:

```
Text(line.text).onDrag {
    sharedState.dragStarted = true
```